# Resolving dependencies in Integration test in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core API. I have already gone through documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) that shows how to do integration testing in asp.net core. The example sets up a test server and then invoke controller method.
However I want to test a particular class method directly (not a controller method)? For example:

```
  public class MyService : IMyService
  {
      private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

      public MyService(DbContext dbContext)
      {
          _dbContext = dbContext;
      }

      public void DoSomething()
      {
          //do something here
      }             
  }
```

When the test starts I want `startup.cs` to be called so all the dependencies will get register. (like dbcontext) but I am not sure in integration test how do I resolve `IMyService`?

Note: The reason I want to test `DoSomething()` method directly because this method will not get invoked by any controller. I am using `Hangfire` inside this API for background processing. The Hangfire's background processing job will call `DoSomething()` method. So for integration test I want to avoid using Hangfire and just directly call `DoSomething()` method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have a `TestServer` when you run integration tests, from here you can easily access the application wide container. You can't access the RequestServices for obvious reason (it's only available in HttpContext, which is created once per request).

```cs
var testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseEnvironment("DevelopmentOrTestingOrWhateverElse"));

var myService = testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
```

Comment: i used var service = (IMyService)_server.Host.Services.GetService(typeof(IMyService));

Comment: That's the same, the extension methods are just more convenient as you don't need to cast or do any null-checks (`GetRequiredService throws if service can't be resolved, hence the **Required** in its name)

Comment: ahh its extension method.:) thats why i couldn't find it on `_server.Host.Services` that helped

Comment: Hitting `Ctrl`+`.` on the error would told you how to resolve it :P

Comment: this is no a universal approach. You may have no webhost builder, while it's a library with repositories and knows nothing about web, startup file and so on. But it still should be tested.